# Python 2.6.6 - Need to add the output of OS.system command into another OS.system command

Tags: python

Below is the script for searching a input data in a given OS.system command ( copied to file out.txt) and prints the line of the given input data. Now I want to put the output i.e line in another OS.system command. For example `symaccess -sid 567 show -name xxx -type init` where xxx is the output of the previous OS.system command i.e line.

Note - I can use only python 2.6.6 and the scripts related to storage

```
import os
os.system('symaccess -sid 456 list -type init > out.txt')
server = raw_input("server name:")
with open('out.txt', 'rt') as in_f:
     for line in in_f:
              if server in line:
                 print line
```

I used another method as below
import os server = raw_input("server name:")

var = "symaccess -sid 239 list -type init | grep \"{0}\"".format(server)

wwn = os.system(var)

init = 'symaccess -sid 239 -type init show {0}'.format(wwn) print init os.system(init)

above is the script i used to add a output of one os.system to another os.syste,. i got the first os.system executed but for the second one i.e os.system(init) is not coming because os.system(var) should be assigned as a variable.could someone tell how to assign a variable to os.system(init)

Comment: import os

server = raw_input("server name:")

var = "symaccess -sid 239 list -type init | grep \"{0}\"".format(server)

wwn = os.system(var)

init = 'symaccess -sid 239 -type init show {0}'.format(wwn)

print init

os.system(init)

Comment: above is the script i used to add a output of one os.system to another os.syste,. i got the first os.system executed but for the second one i.e os.system(init) is not coming because os.system(var) should be assigned as a variable.could someone tell how to assign a variable to os.system(init)

Answer (score 4):

```
import subprocess
cmd= 'ls'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
std_out = p.communicate()
```

Here is a possible way to access the output in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "subprocess.checkoutput()".

```
import subprocess
import os
output = subprocess.check_output(['symaccess -sid 456 list -type init'])
os.system(output)
```

Comment: subprocess.checkoutput() is New in version 2.7. OP needs 2.6.6 (though may have added this after your answer).